# Angular 13 : Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular13

So overnight my code has just gone bananas. In all my components that make use of `*ngIf` I am getting the following error on SomeComponent.html file:

```
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

HTML Source code:

```
<div *ngIf="!admin"></div>
```

I am also recieving the following in the somecomponent.component.ts file for animations:

```
Error during template compile of 'SomeComponent'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called
```

.TS code snippet:

```
animations: [
trigger('detailExpand', [
  state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
  state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
  transition(
    'expanded <=> collapsed',
    animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')
  ),
]),
```

I have reviewed almost every issue I can find on stackoverflow and no solution seems to work.

I can confirm the following:

- Using VS Code Version: 1.69.2
- Extention cersions: Angular Essentials v13.0.0, Angular Snippets v13.0.0, Angular Language Services v14.1.0 (I have tried installing older version and still have the same issue)
- Angular 13
- I have imported `BrowserModule` in `app.module.ts` and added it to `imports:[]`
- I have added CommonModule, no change so removed it as BrowserModule re-exports CommonModule (https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule)
- I have toggled the `Use Legacy View Engine language service setting`, but this setting is incompatible with Angular 13: [image: Screenshot of settings page]

The code still compiles successfully and project runs as expected without any issues so not sure what is going on.

Comment: Check your .html: be sure you use `[@detailExpand]="yourVariable"` or you dind't forgot a quote or similar. Check also from where are you import the trigger ans animations (should be from `'@angular/animations';` Sorry I can  not imagine what are bad

Comment: Hi @Eliseo, so on all my html files throught all my components I am getting things like 'mat-dialog-content' / 'mat-icon' / 'mat-form-field' etc is not a known element. So I am assuming something isn't being picked up from the app.module.ts. Even removing everything and adding back one thing at a time doesn't resolve the issues.

Comment: have you added your component to declarations of your module?

Comment: @devmiles.com, I have indeed.

Comment: Is there any error in your app.module?

Comment: @UchihaMadara, no errors coming up in app.module.ts.

Comment: If I disable the Angular Language Service extension in VS Code then the errors stop appearing. But I can't think that this is a wise workaround?